# Completing dashed line shapefile feature that was created with ArcScan?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vectorization, arcscan

Using ArcScan to vectorize a raster floodplain boundary map, I have selected the area, run ArcScan in the area, to output a Shapefile of the line. ArcScan worked to create the line, and it is a dashed line, so it created a dashed line. However, I need to connect the line. I have used the editor, continue line and connected them at the end points, but I was wondering if there is any way I can automate the joining of the dashed line.

I have tried:

Advanced Editing, Extend Tool, but it only works if the lines are perpendicular to one another.

Editor, Buffer, did not work

I am thinking if I could save the ShapeFile, then re-rasterize it, use ArcScan again on the cleaner dashed line, and then turn on the ArcScan/Vectorization Settings, Gap Closure Tolerance and then it would close the gaps.

I will post images below.

[image]

Comment: It is easier to play with raster to create extent as  area filled. Convert it to polygon after. Perhaps even convert what you have to few millions of points and triangulate. Delineate TIN after.